# Are there any Ruby MVC web frameworks with great support for logic-less templates?

Tags: ruby, templates, frameworks, mustache

I've been on the hunt for a Ruby MVC web framework with support for logic-less templates (i.e. Mustache) for a while now. I'm looking for this:

1. Support for routing paths and HTTP methods
2. Concept of controllers and helpers similar to how Rails works
3. Separate (from the controllers) views with logic-less templates

In my search I've touched Rails, Sinatra and Ramaze, but they all fail on some aspect of what I'm looking for; all attempts I've seen of integrating Mustache into Rails have been half-baked; Sinatra doesn't give me the concept of controllers (and Mustache::Sinatra makes strange assumptions of namespaces and instantiates views twice unnecessarily sometimes); and Ramaze fails to give me a straight-forward way to bind paths *and* HTTP methods to actions. Of these three I liked Ramaze the most, but the routing issues are a showstopper to me.

I'm open to solutions in any somewhat stable framework, including the mentioned ones if I've missed something there. Also, alternatives to Mustache are fine even though I prefer it to other logic-less template languages due to its easy syntax and many implementations in different languages (using the same templates for dynamic views in the browser is one of my goals).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look at [Padrino](http://www.padrinorb.com/), it's based on Sinatra, but is more of a MVC framework than Sinatra is out of the box.

Comment: Padrino seems to be the closest to an answer to this so I'm accepting your answer, although I have to admit I'll go another route with the project. Thanks for taking time to answer :).

Answer (score 0):

Sinatra and Slim could be an answer.

But then you might have missed Renee, a new "framework" like Sinatra.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but both of these seem to fail on the controllers part, or am I missing something? Also, I'm not looking to replace HTML (like Slim does), just template it. Renee seems interesting for other stuff though, so thanks for the tip :).

Answer (score 0):

Ruby on Rails is the best framework for ruby.